# add dimension to multidimensional array JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a dimension to my multidimensional array called `description`. The objective is to go through the array, count the children and add a "parent" dimension based on the number of elements existing in `description`. But i'm currently stuck trying to append information into my array. I want to add this "parent" dimension, or at least be able to put a string into the location `description[x]["TimeSeries"]["parent"]`. Any help on how to proceed?

```
(function () {
 var description;
 description = {
     1: {
         source: "http://beat.entrayn.com/render?width=550&from=-2hours&until=-&height=570&colorList=FFFFFF%2C%20BBBBBB&target=*.entraynec2_ldb01.load.load5&target=*.entraynec2_ldb01.load.load1&title=DB%20EC2%20Load&_uniq=0.9870549130719155&format=json",
         TimeSeries: {
             //parent: "#hero-three",
             title: "Clients Installed"
         }
     },
     2: {
         source: "http://beat.entrayn.com/render?width=550&from=-2hours&until=-&height=570&colorList=FFFFFF%2C%20BBBBBB&target=*.entraynec2_ldb01.load.load5&target=*.entraynec2_ldb01.load.load1&title=DB%20EC2%20Load&_uniq=0.9870549130719155&format=json",
         TimeSeries: {
             //parent: '#g2-1'
         }
     },
     3: {
         source: "http://beat.entrayn.com/render?width=550&from=-2hours&until=-&height=570&colorList=FFFFFF%2C%20BBBBBB&target=*.entraynec2_ldb01.load.load5&target=*.entraynec2_ldb01.load.load1&title=DB%20EC2%20Load&_uniq=0.9870549130719155&format=json",
         TimeSeries: {
             //parent: 
         }
     }
 };

 $(description[3]["TimeSeries"]["parent"]).append('g2-2');

 var g = new Graphene;
 g.build(description);
 alert(description[3]["TimeSeries"]["parent"]);
 }).call(this);
```

Comment: Try to ask your doubt more clear.

Comment: Please format your code to make it more readable.

Comment: First of all, there is no array in your code - arrays are defined with `[]` not `{}`.

Comment: Okay, just tell us what you really want. From your code: you are trying to call method `append(...)` of nonexistent object lying under `description[3]["TimeSeries"]["parent"]`. In fact `TimeSeries` object doesn't have key `parent` yet. I assume you expect string `'g2-2'` to be appended to an array lying under index `parent`. From your description: 'add a "parent" dimension based on the number of elements existing in `description`'. So tell us, what is the relation between `'g2-2'` and the number of elements existing in `description`?

Comment: what i want to do is to be able to, for example, add content to description[3]["Timeseries"]["parent"]...or better yet, create parent under TimeSeries and assign a value to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to note here; so hopefully this should help improve your approach to what you're trying to achieve, and also answer your question in the process.

The first thing to consider is that you're **not** using a multi-dimensional array, you're actually using an `object`. The syntax for an array is `var myArray = [];` whereas you're using `var myObject = {};`. This isn't necessarily a bad thing... objects are good!

From what I can gather, you've actually got an `array` of `Description` objects. If this is the case you'd want to construct it like so...

```
var descriptions = [
    {
        source: '...',
        timeSeries: {
            parent: '...',
            title: '...'
        }
    },
    {
        source: '...',
        timeSeries: {
            parent: '...',
            title: '...'
        }
    }];
```

You can then access your required information by doing the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < descriptions.length; i++) {
    var current = descriptions[i];
    current.timeSeries.parent = '...';
}
```

Comment: read this https://github.com/jondot/graphene - you have an example structure he needs to configure Graphene - your proposal is not accurate. I also pointed out a long time ago, that he is not using arrays, as he thought.

Answer (score 0):

You need to walk through your object. [jquery's _.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function can help you doing this:

```
var description = {
    1: {
        source: "http://beat.entrayn.com/render?width=550&from=-2hours&until=-&height=570&colorList=FFFFFF%2C%20BBBBBB&target=*.entraynec2_ldb01.load.load5&target=*.entraynec2_ldb01.load.load1&title=DB%20EC2%20Load&_uniq=0.9870549130719155&format=json",
        TimeSeries: {
            //parent: "#hero-three",
            title: "Clients Installed"
        }
    },
    2: {
        source: "http://beat.entrayn.com/render?width=550&from=-2hours&until=-&height=570&colorList=FFFFFF%2C%20BBBBBB&target=*.entraynec2_ldb01.load.load5&target=*.entraynec2_ldb01.load.load1&title=DB%20EC2%20Load&_uniq=0.9870549130719155&format=json",
        TimeSeries: {
            //parent: '#g2-1'
        }
    },
    3: {
        source: "http://beat.entrayn.com/render?width=550&from=-2hours&until=-&height=570&colorList=FFFFFF%2C%20BBBBBB&target=*.entraynec2_ldb01.load.load5&target=*.entraynec2_ldb01.load.load1&title=DB%20EC2%20Load&_uniq=0.9870549130719155&format=json",
        TimeSeries: {
         //parent: 
        }
    }
};

var parents = ["parent1", "parent2", "parent3"];

$.each(description, function (key, value) {
    value["TimeSeries"]["parent"] = parents.shift();
});

console.log(description);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yJKr9/2/ or using [underscore each](http://underscorejs.org/#each): http://jsfiddle.net/yJKr9/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$(description[3]["TimeSeries"]["parent"]).append('g2-2');
```

Use:

```
description[3]["TimeSeries"]["parent"] = 'Whatever you want';
```

Using jQuery here is weird.

Also:

```
var g = new Graphene; //This is bad
var g = new Graphene(); //This is good
```

However, I haven't used Graphene, so I don't know if it requires some arguments for constructor. To test proper assignment of `parent` i removed Graphene related lines from my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f9LaC/

Comment: That doesn't seem to work though. What the "parent" index does here is specify a place for a graph to be placed in my main html file..g2-2 refers to a location on that page.. i tried using jQuery i.e, use the extend function but that doesn't work either.. it's like i can't change values from outside the object..

Comment: This is not true, what you are saying - try problem is with initializing Graphene - see http://jsfiddle.net/f9LaC/ - removed two lines from your code.

Comment: Thanks.. there was a problem with the intitialization..also, can i use extend to add "parent"? if so, what's the syntax? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean jQuery `.extend(...)` - no, this is applicable only to jQuery collections - using them in this context is weird, as I said. What would be the benefits of using `extend` here?

Comment: I'm no sure about your second part. I thought the new keyword automatically runs the function passed to it. I'm pretty sure new Graphene is correct. new Graphene() would only be correct if the Graphene function returned a function that was the actual constructor.

Comment: @Rachet, first of all this is what finally solved his problem, secondly https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp Generally, even if `new Graphene` may work on some browsers - it is more readable, when we see braces indicating that we actually call a function. And suppose constructor takes arguments - how would you pass them without braces?